# How to use tf.gather_nd to select from images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a CNN output tensor `X` of shape (N,256,256,5), where `N` is the batch dimension.  I have tensors `x` and `y` containing N indices (each 0 to 255).  I'd like to use these indices to form a (N,5) tensor `Y` such that `Y[n,:] = X[n, x[n], y[n], :]`. How can this be done?

Comment: what is small "n" in your example ?

Comment: An arbitrary integer.  It should work for all n in 0:N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something similar to this could do the trick for you (if I understood your question correctly):

Your data:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 5
D=2
data = tf.constant(np.array(range(batch_size * D * D * 5)).reshape([batch_size, D, D, 5]))
```

Calculate indices:

```py
batches = tf.reshape(tf.range(batch_size, dtype=tf.int32), shape=[batch_size, 1])

random_x = tf.random.uniform([batch_size, 1], minval = 0, maxval = D, dtype = tf.int32)
random_y = tf.random.uniform([batch_size, 1], minval = 0, maxval = D,  dtype = tf.int32)

indices = tf.concat([batches, random_x, random_y], axis=1)
```

Note that `random_x` and `random_y` can be replaced by your existing `x` and `y` tensors. Use the `tf.gather_nd` function then to apply your `indices` to your tensor `data`:

```py
output = tf.gather_nd(data, indices)

print(batches, 'batches')
print(random_x, 'random_x')
print(random_y, 'random_y')
print(indices, 'indices')
print('Original tensor \n', data, '\n')
print('Updated tensor \n', output)
```

```py
'''
tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]], shape=(5, 1), dtype=int32) batches

tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]
 [1]], shape=(5, 1), dtype=int32) random_x

tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]], shape=(5, 1), dtype=int32) random_y

tf.Tensor(
[[0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]
 [2 1 0]
 [3 0 0]
 [4 1 0]], shape=(5, 3), dtype=int32) indices

Original tensor

 tf.Tensor(
[[[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
   [ 5  6  7  8  9]]

  [[10 11 12 13 14]
   [15 16 17 18 19]]]


 [[[20 21 22 23 24]
   [25 26 27 28 29]]

  [[30 31 32 33 34]
   [35 36 37 38 39]]]


 [[[40 41 42 43 44]
   [45 46 47 48 49]]

  [[50 51 52 53 54]
   [55 56 57 58 59]]]


 [[[60 61 62 63 64]
   [65 66 67 68 69]]

  [[70 71 72 73 74]
   [75 76 77 78 79]]]


 [[[80 81 82 83 84]
   [85 86 87 88 89]]

  [[90 91 92 93 94]
   [95 96 97 98 99]]]], shape=(5, 2, 2, 5), dtype=int32)

Updated tensor

 tf.Tensor(
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [35 36 37 38 39]
 [50 51 52 53 54]
 [60 61 62 63 64]
 [90 91 92 93 94]], shape=(5, 5), dtype=int32)

'''
```

The tensor `output` has a shape of `(batch_size, 5)`. As I said, I am not sure if I understood the question, so feel free to give some feedback.

Comment: This works, thanks.  I discovered a way to use tf.gather as well, which I will post as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This way works using tf.gather (vs. tf.gather_nd as in the original question):

```
tf.gather(tf.gather(X, x, batch_dims=1), y, batch_dims=1)
```